# Version history of aspx file unable to load properly

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, version-history, cache

We saved some `.aspx` file in a SharePoint 2016 on-premise document library.

By daily, a new copy of `.aspx` file is uploaded with same filename (e.g. `report.aspx`).

We found that after open a file in version history (e.g. `report.aspx?PageVersion=12345`) then open other version history (e.g. `report.aspx?PageVersion=45678`) it will not refresh. The same report (12345) is loaded.

We tried open with any other browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) on same page and still not refresh. It seems the cache is stored at server side.

May I know why is it happen and can we work around it?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test again in SharePoint 2016 and i can reproduce your issue.

As an workaround, you can create page in site pages library, and edit page directly instead of upload page with same filename.

Besides, I would recommend you submit a feedback about this issue via the below link for your convenience, thanks.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

It is a place for customers provide feedback about SharePoint products. What’s more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Will do

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2016 and i cannot reproduce your issue.

Check whether the issue exists in other pages. Try to upload another document and compare the results.

Check whether the issue exists in other library.

Check whether other users with full control permissions can see the correct version.

Comment: The apsx files are uploaded by powershell.  Will it make a different?

Comment: I tested upload to another SharePoint 2016 farm and encountered same problem. The latest file always load correctly, old version always cached. Not sure why.